# Frame origin value different from actual value

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to create a text field below a text field programatically but however the value produced is not as expected. The following is my code

```
let surveyItemTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: self.firstDropDownTextField.frame.origin.y + self.firstDropDownTextField.frame.size.height + 8, width: 288, height: 45))
print(self.firstDropDownTextField.frame.origin.y)
print(surveyItemTextField.frame.origin.y)
surveyItemTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
surveyItemTextField.borderStyle = .Line
self.view.addSubview(surveyItemTextField)
```

This is the result

[image]

And the console print value is

109.0

162.0

Comment: try with disabling auto layout.

Comment: if you continue with autolayout then update the constrain also